# Matlab .txt file read using space delimiter

Tags: matlab

I want to read a text file into a matrix using space delimiter.My text file contains information like this:

AJ_Lamas/AJ_Lamas_0001.jpg 58 68 134 134 -2 10 31 43 53 45 
Aaron_Eckhart/Aaron_Eckhart_0001.jpg 63 72 126 126 0 10 34 35 53 
Aaron_Guiel/Aaron_Guiel_0001.jpg 54 67 144 144 -1 10 34 44 58 
Aaron_Patterson/Aaron_Patterson_0001.jpg 47 62 148 148 1 10 44 65 63
Aaron_Peirsol/Aaron_Peirsol_0001.jpg 64 72 127 127 0 10 33 43

I tried :

m=dlmread('D:\MatlabCode\lfw_ffd_ann.txt', ' ')

but it shows some errors:

Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 1u) ==> image_name
face_bbox_x face_bbox_y face_bbox_width face_bbox_height headpose
num_facial_features left_eye_left_x left_eye_left_y left_eye_right_x
left_eye_right_y mouth_left_x mouth_left_y mouth_right

Comment: It seems you may have a header line, you should also think about how you handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really read it itno a matrix, but into a cell and can achieve it with `textscan()`. Supposing you want to read the actuall strings (which I assume because of the file names), it would go something like this:

```
 fid=fopen('D:\MatlabCode\lfw_ffd_ann.txt');
 C=textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter',' ');
 fclose(fid);
```

hope that helps

Comment: Normaly when an answer helps you solve your problems you mark it as accepted or vote it up ;)